# Search grid view created dynamically inside a asp panel using id

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i have created few dynamic grid view inside a panel

Method where i added control

```
pRelaese.Controls.Add(DynamicGrid(dt));
```

i'm saving the grid view id in a hidden variable

i added a button inside a update panel

```
string[] GridName = hdnGridName.Value.Split(',');
      foreach (string GN in GridName)
      {
          GV = this.FindControl("pRelaese").FindControl(GN) as GridView;//tried this
          pnl = (Panel)Page.FindControl("pRelaese");//tried this
          GV = (GridView)pnl.FindControl(GN);//tried this
          if (GV != null)
          {
              foreach (GridViewRow GVR in GV.Rows)
              {
                  //codes
              }
          }
      }
```

But every time null is returned to  GV

i need to find control and insert it into GV to perform of the task

Comment: using dynamic controls in asp.net is a bad idea. you have to create them at each post back.you are getting null because the gridview that you dynamically created got destroyed the moment postback happens. hence you get null. why are you creating a gridview dynamically. create it and keep. it will be invisible if it is not bound to anything. just bind the data when every you want. that way you can search it too.

Comment: im using a update panel for button click

Comment: doesnt matter even partial post back destroys the control. they have to be recreated at every postback even partial ones

Comment: the number of grid that is going to be created is not fixed it is based on the user

Comment: he can create more number of grid based on his requirement

Comment: that kind of functionality is very difficult to implement in asp.net.It should only be used to display data. never to read from it. to make this work you will have to recreate all the gridviews before you search them pRelaese.Controls.Add(DynamicGrid(dt)); will have to be added before the code for searching

Comment: its not a good method. but it could work. but as the number of gridviews increase your it will become slower

Comment: it will create empty grid and the user will enter the data and on save button it will take the data and save the data in database

Comment: that wont work with dynamic grids

Comment: any other way to do it, will be a real help

Comment: not the way you want it. I just created text boxes which would input the data from user save it and display it in gridview. had similar requirements. but had to settle for this method

Comment: i have a situation where user will enter 5 then 5 grids will appear with 3 columns and user will enter the value and will save it

Comment: you can try this though i have not tried this. using jquery you might be able to create tables and dynamically append them to your div. It could work

Comment: $("#DivName").append("<table Id="tab1"><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>")

Comment: thank you i will try jquery